Magnitude of a complex number's factorial.
In a problem I was doing the magnitude of this complex number appeared:
$$q=\left(-x^{\frac{1}{3}}\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{3}i\right)}{2}\right)!$$
I know that there's an analytic solution for the magnitude of $i!$, being $$\left|i!\right|=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}}}$$
And was wondering if there was some similar solution for $\left|q\right|$.
If not, perhaps it's possible to instead find the derivative of $\left|q\right|$ with respect to $x$ evaluated at $x=0$.
I would appreciate an answer for either of these or even both, and if it's not possible to find an analytic solution, I would appreciate if you told me.
Thank you.

Check the identities of the gamma function.

@LeeFisher Don't see anything that can help me all that much, the only analytic solutions seem to be for integers or half-integers.

There is a problem close to $x=0$ since, at this point, the derivative of $\Re(q)$, $\Im(q)$ and $| q|$ are infinite. Otherwise, it is a trivial gamma function
